# For a Gaussian Random walk where $x_n$ is the sum of $n$ normal random variables, what is $P(x_1 >0, x_2 >0)$?

Tags: probability, random-walk

I know that the events $x_1 >0$ and $x_2 >0$ are not independent, but I can't think of a way to find a conditional probability so I can solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably (but this ought to be in the question), $x_2=x_1+y$ where $(x_1,y)$ is i.i.d. and standard normal. In particular, one assumes the increments are **centered** and with the **same variance**. Then, a picture in the $(x_1,y)$ plane reveals that $(x_1\gt0,y+x_1\gt0)$ is the angular sector going from the North to the South-East through North-East and East.

Thus, this sector is $\frac38$ of the whole. The distribution of $(x_1,y)$ is invariant by every rotation centered at $(0,0)$ hence $P[x_1\gt0,x_2\gt0]=\frac38$.

Comment: I think I understood this. I just drew the (x1,y) plane and drew the line y = -x1. Then I shaded the intersection of x1 >0 and y + x1 >0. That results in 3/8 of the plane shaded. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, a picture just shows it.

Comment: Exactly. This geometric approach works because $e^{-x^2/2}\cdot e^{-y^2/2}$ is rotation symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is:

$$
\begin{align}
x_1&=\epsilon_1\\
x_2&=\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2
\end{align}
$$
where $\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. The probability you want is:

$$
Pr(x_1 >0, x_2>0)=Pr(x_2>0\mid x_1>0)Pr(x_1>0)
$$

The second term is 1/2, but the first one still needs some work. Are you able to continue by yourself?

Comment: Pr(x2>0∣x1>0) is exactly what i can't figure out. I'm still trying to think of a way to go about finding that.
Thank you so much!